# Trait method roles has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\User

Tags: php, laravel, traits, laravel-5.7

Here in my code i have used ZizacoEntrust package for authentication. And following [ACL tutorial](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-user-roles-and-permissions-acl-using-spatie-tutorialexample.html) step by step
When i`m trying to run code, in browser it shows error like in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9v6F.png)

> **Error Message**:
>   "Trait method roles has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\User"

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    use HasRoles;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

I don`t know what exactly happening here. In tutorial used - Spatie, for some moments i used to use zizaco. nothing additional.

Comment: One of the other traits you are using in this class is using the same method names. Specifically the `roles` method

Comment: Traits add functions to a class. Function names need to be unique within a class. If 2 Traits add a function with the same name, you will get this result. This is a comment because I do not provide a solution for your specific problem, only insight.

Comment: Please share the whole error message in text form, not in images

Answer (score 0):

You can rename that method like so:

```
class User {
    use YourTrait {
        roles as protected traitRoles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone is stumbling upon this issue in 2022, as I have, I received the same error but the case was that I had accidentally duplicated the use MyTrait statement. The solution was to remove the duplicated `use` statement. However, this didn't cause any issues in terms of breaking the code.